# Signal from subclassed QGraphicsView not being recognized in SLOT

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, qgraphicsview

I have a subclass of QGraphicsView to recognize mouse events, and it does. But when those mouse events happen, I need to call some other function in a different class, to handle how the mouse event interacts with the scene.

```
//Subclass
class Drawspace : public QGraphicsView {
public:
    Drawspace(QGraphicsScene * scene, QWidget * parent) : QGraphicsView(scene, parent) {}
    Drawspace(QWidget* parent) : QGraphicsView(parent) {}

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event) { 
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Dialog"), "You clicked the board (from QGraphicsView)");
        QWidget::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
};

//mainwindow code (my subclass is called "board")
mainwindow::mainwindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent) {

    //Initialize other stuff
    ui.setupUi(this);

    //Problem here
    connect(ui.board, SIGNAL(Drawspace::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent*)), this, SLOT(on_click(QMouseEvent*)));
}

void mainwindow::on_click(QMouseEvent * event) {
    QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Dialog"), "You clicked the screen");
    //Do stuff here
}
```

It builds fine, and when I click the drawspace, I get a dialog that says "You clicked the board (from QGraphicsView)", but I don't get the second from "You clicked the screen".
And yes, the header file for mainwindow has the Q_OBJECT macro

EDIT: Can be fixed by manually defining your own signal, calling that, and changing the connection to use Qt5 syntax. See my answer for code

Comment: I haven't see any `mousePressEvent` signal declared at `Drawspace` class

Answer (score 1):

OP here, the problem can be fixed by defining a signal, calling emit on it and changing the connection to use Qt5 syntax.

```
//New drawspace: Added signal definition and called emit on it from mousePressEvent
class Drawspace : public QGraphicsView, public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Drawspace(QGraphicsScene * scene, QWidget * parent) : QGraphicsView(scene, parent) {}
    Drawspace(QWidget* parent) : QGraphicsView(parent) {}
    void setObjectName(QString str) { QGraphicsView::setObjectName(str); }

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event) {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Dialog"), "Detected click in Drawspace");
        emit clicked(event);
    }

Q_SIGNALS:
    void clicked(QMouseEvent * event);
};

//Used Qt5 syntax, this will automatically pass arguments
connect(ui.board, &Drawspace::clicked, this, &mainwindow::on_click);
```

Comment: Actually `emit` does absolutely nothing, it is just for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Oh well, it looks aesthetic and intuitive

Answer (score 0):

`mousePressEvent()` is not a signal. It is a member function. You cannot `connect()` a function to a function like you can connect a signal to a signal.

Qt signals are declared as functions, but they get some special treatment. You'd need to use Qt's keywords to signify a signal so it can get the treatment that will make it work.

Comment: I looked up the syntax for your suggestion and added it in the edit. However, there's no change in behaviour

Comment: You will need to define your own signal and emit it in `mousePressEvent()`. Also, remove the `Drawspace::` part from the connection.

Comment: Also, shouldn't `ui` be a pointer, thus using the `->` syntax?

Comment: Change to `ui->board`

Comment: And no to the pointer. That part was autogenerated and I never felt the need to change it.

Comment: Also, if you use Qt5, you might want to use the new syntax, which is compile time safe, whereas the current one may silently fail at runtime. I don't use auto generated forms, but IIRC `ui` is precisely a pointer. Check out the new connection syntax: https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax A little more verbose, especially if you have overloads, but it would be preferable to use that.

Comment: It is strange that you got `ui.stuff` auto generated. It should be a pointer and that code shouldn't compile as it is. What version of Creator are you using?

Comment: 5.8, but I'm not using creator, I'm using the Visual Studio plugin with Designer.

Comment: Maybe the implementation for VS is different. It's been a while since I used VS, luckily I might add :) Also not a big fan of form generators.

Answer (score -1):

Make the mousePressEvent virtual, or you are creating a NEW method:

virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event)

and say it is overriden (depending on your compiler:)

virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * event) override (Q_DECL_OVERRIDE)

Comment: Nope, that is not true, if the one in the base class is virtual, the override is implicitly virtual as well. What would create a new method is a different signature, that is different parameters or return value.

Comment: That doesn't change anything.

Comment: You are getting the message implemented in the actual event handler, so it is not an issue with signature mismatch as this incorrect answer suggests.

Comment: My mistake sorry. But I still consider good advice to make the virtual and override explicit.